# Vercel - Next.js 13 - problems when building

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vercel, next.js13

I'm having trouble deploying my Next.js 13.4.4 app on Vercel. I had this app working previously, and I updated my endpoints with the new structure inside the app folder. I also implemented a middleware. Everything works perfectly fine in my local environment, and even building the app locally works correctly. However, the problem arises when I try to deploy it on Vercel, and it throws this error...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EGoD.png)

I'm sharing the screenshot of the complete Vercel log and also the error text in case you want to copy it

`"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"`

`"Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error"`

Something that seems very strange to me is that when I try to redeploy another point where the app was working fine before, it now returns the same error during the build. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

The information I found suggested that I should check the dependencies since this error often occurs when accidentally importing a library. However, that's not the case for me. Another recommendation is to verify if we have a JSON file since it can cause an error if it's structured incorrectly. However, upon reviewing it, I see that everything is correct.

This is my `/app/page.tsx` file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqm5k.png)

Comment: I think you're call an API in app/page.tsx with http://localhost:3000, am i right if not kindly share your code on stackBlitz or codesandbox

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this platform, and I don't know how to share my code, if you want we can get in touch with other means like discord and I have no problem showing you my code, I do have calls to an api but not to "localhost: 3000" and I'm trying to use the new way to create apis in next (inside the app folder)

Comment: I just added an image at the end of the description, I think I can't put it in the comments

Comment: To add code, you can copy it, paste it in here, select all the text that is code, and press `ctrl + k` or just add 3 of this character `  at the beginning and end of code! for one line code, just add one ` at beg and end. @AndresBarilin